# CSS 'snap-scroll' interfering with jQuery '.animate scrollLeft'

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an html and css slider where I'm using `scroll-snap` for manual scrolling and jQuery buttons for automatic scrolling. However, when using `scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;`, the jQuery `scrollLeft` animation becomes extremely laggy or the animation disappears. Where is this lag coming from? Is there a jQuery only solution?

Taking out the css scroll-snap fixes the problem, but the style is necessary to the slider.

HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div> 
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<button id="left">&larr;</button>
<button id="right">&rarr;</button>
```

CSS

```css
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.box {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 250px;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  scroll-snap-stop: normal;
}
.box:nth-child(1) {background: #f55;}
.box:nth-child(2) {background: #5f5;}
.box:nth-child(3) {background: #5ff;}
```

jQuery

```
$("#right, #left").click(function() {
  var dir = this.id=="right" ? '+=' : '-=' ;
  $(".container").stop().animate({scrollLeft: dir+'300'}, 300);
});
```

Here's a live example: https://codepen.io/tystrong/pen/rboLYz

Comment: If you change the `scroll-snap-type` rule to `scroll-snap-type: x proximity;` or `scroll-snap-type: x;` (which may be the same) you should get some animated scrolling. However, with Chrome 76.0.3809.132 the animated scrolling is janky/not smooth and `scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;` provides a superior UX for my module. Therefore I don't consider this a viable workaround, but wanted to mention for investigation's sake.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue by disabling the `scroll-snap-type` property during the scroll animation. Then in the `animate()` callback I just re-enable it.

Here's my simplified code:

```
$arrows.on("click", event => {
  $track.css("scroll-snap-type", "none");

  $track.stop().animate(
    { scrollLeft: left },
    500,
    () => $track.css("scroll-snap-type", "x mandatory")
  );
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me - the scroll position just reverts to the pre-scrolled position on re-adding mandatory

Answer (score 1):

The [smooth scroll behavior polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) offers a solid alternative to jQuery animate for this side scrolling & snapping problem. Here's how you'd modify your previous example to use it:

```
$('#right, #left').click(function() {
  $('.container')[0].scrollBy({
    top      : 0,
    left     : this.id == 'right' ? 300 : -300,
    behavior : 'smooth'
  });
});
```

1 caveat: you can't control the scroll speed. However, in my testing on desktop Chrome (76.0.3809.132) and mobile Safari (iOS 13.0) it's buttery smooth.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use JavaScript's native [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method on **the element you want to scroll to** (i.e. one of the boxes inside your scroller). Using this method, the native scroll-snap behaviour (and animations) will be used, and will be - if available - GPU accelerated: it'll look smooth and native.

In your case it would be something like:

```
var boxes = $(".box", ".container");
var animate_to_id = 1; //make this dynamic, based on the current active id, and where you want to scroll to.

boxes.eq(animate_to_id)[0].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'start',
    inline: 'start'
  });
```

Comment: Works on Chrome, but not on iOS WKWebView (Safari) (iOS 15) =/

Comment: @RodrigoVieira It should work, but it doesn't provide a smooth transition, if I remember correctly. See more info @ https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollIntoView